# Using AJAX to load a partial view not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Forgive me, I am new to MVC and AJAX.

Currently I am simply submitting a form, and I want to use the data from the form to update a table in a partial view using ajax.

My `_UserInfo` partial view looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Dashboard.Models.UserInfo>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
           Firstname
        </th>
        <th>
           Lastname
        </th>
        <th>
            EmailAddress
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.surname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emailAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SAMuserName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

My main `User` view looks like this:

```
@model Dashboard.Models.User
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_UserInfo", "User", new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            UpdateTargetId = "results",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                        }))
{

    <fieldset>
    //...My Form 

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Find" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div id="results">
</div>
```

And last this is my `UserController`:

```
public PartialViewResult UserResults(User person)
{
    UserInfo personInfo = new UserInfo();

    //....Doing stuff

    return PartialView("_userInfo", personInfo);
}
```

---

Now I know this probably isnt good. But this is the best attempt I have tried with my little knowledge.

When I click the button on the User view, I am getting a 404 error saying that _UserInfo cannot be found.

I believe that the source of all of my issues is in

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_UserInfo", "User", new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            UpdateTargetId = "results",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                        }))
```

But with my knowledge, I don't know what is wrong.

---

**EDIT:**As it has been pointed out to me, I was creating my HTML form incorrectly. I have since changed  it to

> @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UserResults", "User", new
>   AjaxOptions(){...}

My action is now being called! However, my partial view is not being loaded onto the screen.

Comment: When you define the BeginForm, you need to pass in the ActionName, then the Controller. The way you have it set up, you are calling the _UserInfo action method in the userResultController.

Comment: Thank you I fixed that issue. But now my Action is getting called, but my partial view is not being loaded onto the screen.

Comment: usually, when submitting a form, the POST method is used: HttpMethod = "POST" and decorate the action method with `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: I have tried that also, but my partial is still not rendering.

Comment: I see once you type _UserInfo and once _userInfo , check that out and see if you have Ajax unobtrusive in your scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific overload, the first two strings are ActionName and ControllerName [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  As such, it should mirror your controller like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("userResults", "User", new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "GET",
                        UpdateTargetId = "results",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                    }))
```

In addition, it's worth noting that in following naming conventions, userResults SHOULD be renamed to UserResults

**EDIT:**
Make sure that you are using both Ajax.BeginForm (see update) and that you also have included the ajax unobtrusive script into your bundle.  In BundleConfig.RegisterBundles, you should have the follow bundle addition.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

And in your HTML, make sure both bundles are called.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: Thanks David. I will change that.

However now that I changed this, my Action is being called. But my partial view is not being loaded onto the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I have triple checked that to make sure it is there. I have also manually added the unobtrusive.

I am beginning to think my issue is elsewhere than what I specified in my post.

But again, thank you. This has helped me get my original code fixed.

Comment: In the console of your browser, do you see the partial view response being returned?  And what happens when you actually click on the button and fire off the call?  Does it load to another page or does it remain on the page?

Comment: I don't see anything in my results div in the developer console after I submit. However I have a breakpoint at my `return PartialView("_UserInfo", personInfo)` ant it is being caught.

Comment: Actually. I just saw that my console is saying Uncaught `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:163`

Comment: There it is!  You just need jquery defined before jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.  So that reference bundle probably isn't being included

Comment: That for sure helped. I didn't realize I had to have jquery defined since I had it in my layout. now my last issue is this `GET http://localhost:50859/Users/UserResults?Name=whismj&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: `[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Dashboard.Models.UserInfo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Dashboard.Models.UserInfo]'.]`....

Comment: Because it looks like based on the foreach loop in your code that you're posting back a List or IEnumerable of users, not a single User.

Comment: I have got it figured out! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

U need to use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("userResults", "User", new AjaxOptions()
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    UpdateTargetId = "results",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                }));
```

Comment: And be sure to include Ajax unobtrusive

Comment: I have made that change, but am still not getting my partial view to render.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good.
Is necessary add the script:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));

@model Dashboard.Models.User
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_UserInfo", "User", new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            UpdateTargetId = "results",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                        }))
{

    <fieldset>
    //...My Form 

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Find" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div id="results">
</div>
```

Now, your code could works.